# Canon Pixma MG2522 Does not print

Tags: drivers, printing, canon, pixma

I have a Canon Pixma MG2522. I have used it with documents in the past and it has worked well.

I recently updated Ubuntu to the most recent distribution and now my printer will not

**The Print jobs do not post.**

The printer is a local printer directly connected by usb to the computer.

**What I've done:**

- I inspected to see if the printer had simply died.  I ran the scan and test page function locally in the printer and it functions.  It appears there is something interfering with the communication between the OS and the printer.
- I have gone through the settings, deleted and reinstalled the drivers with the same results.
- I have manually gone to the European server (The american server doesn't have a Linux driver), downloaded, and installed the drivers through terminal using gdebi.  I have run into the same result.

*The printer posts and is recognized but the jobs do not post on the system.  They do not print.*

Any help or assistance would be wonderful.  I'd rather not need to cab my way to the Library when I had a working printer 2 weeks ago, or rufus a fresh older copy of Ubuntu to get access to my hardware.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you have properly installed the drivers. It should not say  "Generic Text Only Printer". I have no experience adding a USB printer, only networked, but you should add the printer, then go through the dialogs selecting Canon / MG2500 / etc.  If you can add info from the Printer Properties dialog that would be good. (I am talking about the dialog you get when you give the command `system-config-printer` in a terminal, then click the printer image, then Properties.)

Comment: Specifically which release number do you have right now; 20.04, 19.10, or 18.04?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue just now on Ubuntu 20.10 (Budgie) with the exact same printer, after having it work fine on Manjaro, Mint, and Deepin. I was able to fix it by installing the `cups-backend-bjnp` package:

`sudo apt install cups-backend-bjnp`

Then, I did need to go to "Printers" in settings, and add a new printer; once that package is installed, it will auto-detect the printer again and match it with the drivers from that package, but Ubuntu won't match them retroactively to existing printer profiles.

Comment: This worked, thank you.

Comment: This answer works as of November 2022. Thank you!

Comment: The Answer by Andrew worked great! It helped out with my other usb devices somehow also. It sped up my usb wifi dongle substantially! Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 1):

Fixed mine today. For MG2522. Clicked Activities. Typed in Printers. Or get into settings. You will see printer MG2500 as MG2522 is not recognized. Select printer details. Scroll down...ehem, way down, to the older cannon driver MG2490. Select. It's the same as previous driver. You should be able to do the same through terminal, but I didn't bother as this was simpler.